# What type of construction is verb+"se", like in the word "veíase"?

Tags: verbos, conjugación, pretérito-imperfecto, voz-pasiva, morfología

I am reading a children's novel, *El león, la bruja y el ropero*, translated into Spanish by the Chilean editorial group Andrés Bello.  I came across a form of *ver* that I can't explain.  In context, several children are walking along the top of a narrow dam in the winter:

> A un costado se encontraba, al mismo nivel, esa gran superficie helada; y al otro **veíase** una brusca caída hacia el fondo del río.

This looks like a passive *se*, paralleled by *se encontraba*, so I would have written *se veía*, but that's not what is found here.  I'm speculating that it's related to the archaic/literary *érase* (as in "érase una vez"), but I'm not sure how.

What is this construction called? What rules govern it (only certain verbs, only imperfect indicative, etc.)?

¿Cómo se llama la forma gramática de la palabra *veíase* en el pasaje supra?  Respuestas en español están bienvenidas también.

Comment: _veía_ es el preterito imperfecto/copreterito del verbo ver.  Respecto a _se_ correctamente lo identificaste y se puede reemplazar por _se veía_. En inglés creo que seria equivalente a _it was seen_ o también a _it could be seen_

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En el español literario, es algo más frecuente encontrar **enclisis**, o el posicionamiento de un pronombre átono después del verbo (y en tal caso, se escribe junto al verbo, tildando si es necesario).  No había restricción en los tiempos verbales ni en los verbos.  Las reglas de su uso varían a lo largo de la historia del español, pero por lo general eran estas:

- Si el verbo iniciaba la frase, era obligatoria.
- Si el verbo iba en negativa, era prohibida.
- Si algo enfático (adverbios, pronombres relativos, objetos contrastivos) iba en frente del verbo, era menos probable y a veces imposible.
- Si el verbo venía después de una pausa leve, era más probable.
- En los tiempos futuro y condicional, y en el español más o menos del siglo XV para atrás, era posible *mesoclisis*, y los pronombres iban dentro del verbo: *ver**se**ía* (se vería), *dar**melo**ás* (me lo darás)

Hay algunos hablantes en el noroeste de España, sean también hablantes o no del gallego o asturiano, en los cuales la enclisis es regla fija, que lo hacen naturalmente hoy día, pero para los demás hispanohablantes, es decir, la plena mayoría, hacerlo puede tener connotaciones arcaicas o literarias, como bien dices de *érase* (excepto que *érase* queda hoy más como fórmula idiomática).  Ya que la editorial es chilena, no sé qué le habrá ocurrido al traductor emplear la enclisis, especialmente si no la emplea comúnmente en otras partes del libro.  *Paréceme* raro. :-)

Comment: Interesantísima respuesta que no vi en su momento. Me pica la curiosidad: cuando dices _Si el verbo iba en negativa, era prohibida_, ¿quieres decir que por ejemplo se diría _veíase_ pero _no se veía_?

Comment: @fedorqui exactamente. Las palabras negativas (sea no o nunca o nadie) en atractores que obligaban proclisis. Seguramente habría algún ejemplo de enclisis pero no recuerdo haber visto un ejemplo contrario

Comment: Son atractores*