# ¿Cuáles eran las reglas sintácticas de la enclisis en el español antiguo?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, español-medieval, enclisis

¿Cuáles eran las reglas sintácticas de la enclisis en el español antiguo?

Según Wikipedia en [Posición de pronombres clíticos en español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posici%C3%B3n_de_pronombres_cl%C3%ADticos_en_espa%C3%B1ol), si el verbo no va precedido de una palabra tónica, el pronombre personal lo sigue por pauta:

> El pronombre seguía el verbo, salvo cuando el verbo estaba precedido (en la misma cláusula) por otra palabra tónica, como sustantivo, adverbio, pronombre tónico, etc.

Ejemplo: *Cómolos todos los días; Enseñómelo Juan* pero *No los como; Juan me lo enseñó*

Allende ésta, no sé mucho sobre las reglas que regían los pronombres clíticos en el español de antaño, pero tengo harto interés en aprender.

Agradeceré cualquier aporte que brindaren.

Comment: Pues sí, si usas el futuro de subjuntivo, debes de tener mucho interés en aprender las formas antiguas.

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22590/20054